# Google Plus Application Dev Language

Tags: web-applications, programming-languages, google-plus

Does anyone know what language the google plus apps need to be written in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APIs, themselves, are REST-ful web-based APIs that simply use standard protocols such as OAuth that are built on top of HTTP, HTTPS, JSON, XML, and other web standards. Code written in a variety of languages can use these APIs by issuing HTTPS and HTTP requests. Google has a bunch of "client libraries" written in a variety of different languages that support their various web-based APIs.

For a list of existing client-libraries that support (some of) the Google+ APIs, see:
http://developers.google.com/+/downloads

Answer (score 0):

As with Facebook, you can access the Google Plus APIs with any programming language.